# Group several values into one sequence using C#

Tags: c#, lambda

I have the following list :

```
UserName  LanguageSpoken
-------------------------
Bob       English
Bob       French
Alan      Italian
Alan      Spanish
Alan      German
```

I'd like to have another list like :

```
Bob       English/French
Alan      Italian/Spanish/German
```

How can I do that using lambda expressions in C#.

Thanks

Comment: When you say "I have the following list", is this in a List<>, a big text blob, or what?

Comment: @lasnog - maybe try my approach (below) and let us know if you get stuck.  Would rather help you learn to solve the problem than just do all the work for you.

Answer (score 2):

My approach would be to use a regex to parse the data and then linq to group it.  Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Below is an implementation that you can play around with.

```
class UserLanguage
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string Language { get; set; }
}

static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static string Concatenate(this IEnumerable<string> source, string delimiter)
    {
        using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(enumerator.Current);
                while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    builder.Append(delimiter).Append(enumerator.Current);
                }
                return builder.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // assuming that you already have data stored in a structure similar to this
        var rawData = new List<UserLanguage>()
        {
            new UserLanguage { UserName = "Bob", Language = "English" },
            new UserLanguage { UserName = "Bob", Language = "French" },
            new UserLanguage { UserName = "Alan", Language = "Italian" },
            new UserLanguage { UserName = "Alan", Language = "Spanish" },
            new UserLanguage { UserName = "Alan", Language = "German" },
        };

        // group these objects together by UserName
        var groupedData = rawData.GroupBy(userLanguage => userLanguage.UserName);

        foreach (var grouping in groupedData)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(grouping.Key + "\t" + grouping.Select(userLanguage => userLanguage.Language).Concatenate("/"));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```cs
class Person
{
    string UserName {get; set;}
    string LanguageSpoken {get; set;}    
}

var table = new List<Person>() {
    new Person() {
        UserName = "Bob";
        LanguageSpoken = "English"
    }
    /* next persons*/
};

var userNameGroups = from n in table
    group n by n.UserName into g
    select new {
        keyUserName = g.Key,
        LanguageSpoken = g
    };

foreach(var g in userNameGroups) {
    Console.Write(g.keyUserName.ToString());
    foreach(var n in g.LanguageSpoken) {
        Console.WriteLine(n.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your List is something like:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
}

List<Person> myList = /* Initialization */
```

Then LINQ GroupBy should do the trick:

```
myList.GroupBy(a => a.Name);
```

Hope this helps.